# Wildcard excel 2013

Tags: excel, ms-access

I am using ms excel 2013. I have made a connection to ms access database and I need to make a select with a like to return a specific value that ends with 3 numbers follows by underscore follows by string. That column value can be:
1 - "sample/023_test" or 
2 - "ssss/ssss/re/test_test_023_tr" or 
3 - "sss/0214_dg"
When I did `select * from table_name where column_name like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][_][a-z]` it returns all values instead of returning only first example.
I don't know how the pattern should be used. Thanks

Comment: hum, all the values you give as example _have_ 3 numbers followed by an underscore followed by a string of letters at the end (023_test, 023_tr and 214_dg)

Comment: I need to take only string after last slash (/). It should only be numbers (like 023) follows by underscore (_) follows by string (abc): /012_string. Not this /stringOrNumber_012_string

Comment: YOu need to add the slash to your statement `like '%[/][0-9][0-9][0-9][_][a-z]` (NB this is untested)

Comment: Do you need just the number `23` or `0214`? OR do you need the complete last string? Something like `023_test` or `0214_dg`? Can you use VBA to design an UDF function to acomplish this?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns  I need the complete last string. ( I will check how to use vba.). cybernetic.nomad it returns an empty result

Comment: If your data is store in an Access Database, you can just insert a module and a Public Function (UDF) to extract the data you need as a calculated query in Excel :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use and UDF (USer Defined Function) to calculate the specific value you want to extract. Then in your query call, call to the calculated field.

The UDF I designed extracts the last string after last slash "/".

```
Public Function SPECIFIC_VALUE(ByVal ThisString As String) As String
Dim MyStrings() As String
MyStrings() = Split(ThisString, "/")

'the value we want is at the end of string always, so inside array MyStrings, it will be always Ubound

SPECIFIC_VALUE = MyStrings(UBound(MyStrings))
End Function
```

Results from this UDF in Excel:

[image]

You can call this function in a query in Access just typing `SPECIFIC_VALUE([Fieldname])`

Remember to Insert a Module in Access and Paste the code of the UDF there

> [(HOW TO INSERT A
>   MODULE)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd897495(v=office.12).aspx)